# Define a circe that circumscribes a set of points (shapefile) in python

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have a shapefile of points, defined by X and Y coordinates, ad the ID feature.
I have at least 3 different points with the same ID number.

I would like to define, for each ID, the shapefile of a circle that circumscribes the points.

How can this be done in python environment?

Comment: Do you know how to do this on paper?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you are given 3 or more points as (x, y) coordinates, do you know what calculations you need to do (without Python) in order to determine the circle you are looking for?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121987/how-to-find-the-incircle-and-circumcircle-for-an-irregular-polygon

I'm intrested in something like this, but considering points as starting points

Comment: So you are trying to solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem? That Wikipedia article shows some algorithms, what happened when you tried to translate them to Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- there is a library that does it: https://pypi.org/project/miniball/
- it's pretty forward to integrate in standard **pandas** pattern https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html
- solution really reduces to this:

```
def circle(points):
    p, r = miniball.get_bounding_ball(np.array([points.x, points.y]).T)
    return shapely.geometry.Point(p).buffer(math.sqrt(r))

col = "group"
# generate circles around groups of points
gdf_c = cities.groupby(col, as_index=False).agg(geometry=("geometry", circle))
```

- with sample example and visualisation, circles do become distorted due to **epsg:4326** projection limitations

#### full working example

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely
import miniball
import math
import pandas as pd

cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# a semi-synthetic grouping of cities
world["size"] = world.groupby("continent")["pop_est"].apply(
    lambda d: pd.cut(d, 2, labels=list("ab"), duplicates="drop").astype(str)
)
cities = cities.sjoin(world.loc[:, ["continent", "iso_a3", "size", "geometry"]])
cities["group"] = cities["continent"] + cities["size"]


def circle(points):
    p, r = miniball.get_bounding_ball(np.array([points.x, points.y]).T)
    return shapely.geometry.Point(p).buffer(math.sqrt(r))

col = "group"
# generate circles around groups of points
gdf_c = cities.groupby(col, as_index=False).agg(geometry=("geometry", circle))

# visualize it
m = cities.explore(column=col, height=300, width=600, legend=False)
gdf_c.loc[~gdf_c["geometry"].is_empty].explore(
    m=m, column=col, marker_kwds={"radius": 20}, legend=False
)
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: Here it is! This is the library i needed! Thanks a lot